# How can you find out your progress towards the Curious, Inquisitive & Socratic badges?

Tags: support, badges, badge-progress, asking-days-badges

The Curious, Inquisitive, and Socratic badges were only recently added to Stack Exchange. Is there a way I can find out how many more questions I would need to ask to get these badges?

Similar to the counters for the review-related badges:

[image: Progress towards reviewer and steward]

Comment: Related: [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for/188732#188732)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can query the Stack Exchange Data Explorer. There is a query ready for you: [Progress towards Curious, Inquisitive and Socratic badges](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/229495/progress-towards-curious-inquisitive-and-socratic-badges). The query is an *approximation* because the SEDE doesn't contain deleted posts. The actual counts could be lower depending on how many questions you have deleted in the past. The query also doesn't track your *positive question record* requirement.

Take into account you'll need to use the site switcher below the *Run Query* button to switch between sites, and use your userid *for that site*.

The data is up to a week old (refreshed every Sunday). Up until the last update, you had [no qualifying questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/229495/progress-towards-curious-inquisitive-and-socratic-badges?UserId=3330969) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: It's too bad we can't put this query somewhere in the screen that tracks the badge progress and just run it for people on page load, with a handy visual indicator too. That'd basically be Web 2.0, right?

Answer (score 6):

The best way to do this is by going to your profile and selecting the Socratic badge. You can click on it to see if you have a positive question record or not:

> [image: screenshot of badge progress]

If the number is off, it will only be by one day (but you know what you did today, right?).

Note: This only works the first time you're earning the badge.

As for determining how far you are from a positive question record, you can do that easily if you have the ability to search for deleted posts (usually awarded at 10k):

([total questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?page=6&tab=Relevance&q=deleted%3a*%20user%3ame%20is%3aq) - [negative questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=deleted%3A*+user%3Ame+is%3Aq+score%3A..0) - [closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=deleted%3A*+user%3Ame+is%3Aq+closed%3A1) - [deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=deleted%3A1+user%3Ame+is%3Aq))/total questions >= 0.5

If you don't have the rep, you'll need to manually count your [deleted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/deleted-questions/current).

You can generate the above URLs for the site of your choice by inputting the URL (e.g. `meta.stackexchange.com`) in this snippet I made:

```js
function generate() {
  var url=document.getElementById("url").value
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "<p>(<a href=\"https://"+url+"/search?q=deleted%3a*%20user%3ame%20is%3aq\">total questions</a> - <a href=\"https://"+url+"/search?q=deleted%3A*+user%3Ame+is%3Aq+score%3A..0\">negative questions</a> - <a href=\"https://"+url+"/search?q=deleted%3A*+user%3Ame+is%3Aq+closed%3A1\">closed</a> - <a href=\"https://"+url+"/search?q=deleted%3A1+user%3Ame+is%3Aq\">deleted</a>)/total questions &gt;= 0.5</p><br><p><a href=\"https://"+url+"/users/deleted-questions/current\">Deleted questions for low-rep users</a></p>";
}
```

```html
Site URL: <input type="text" name="url" id="url"><br>
<button onclick="generate()">generate URLs</button><br>
<label id="output">
```

If you don't have the privilege to search for deleted posts, these URLs will return numbers that are off by the number of deleted posts that you have.

Comment: One thing to note: questions that were at least 60 days old before they were closed *don’t count as closed as far as the badge is concerned*, so they should not be included in the “closed” count for the good standing calculation.