# Why haven't I received the "Curious" badge?

Tags: support, badges, profile-page, badge-progress, asking-days-badges

As you can see in the picture, I have 13 out of 5. But it's been like this for about two months! What's the reason for that?

[image: Profile screenshot]

Comment: Most likely you have many (about 5) questions that have been downvoted and deleted (hence not visible in your profile anymore) and as explained [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256469/curious-badge-bug), it cause the badge not to be given. When you will ask more questions that will get positive score, you will eventually get the badge

Comment: So is it a bug on stack if don't reduce these numbers by deleting or downvoting? However I  haven't removed or downvoting question more than one or two as you can see on my questions list...

Comment: You've a number of deleted, downvoted questions per my answer so it's highly unlikely there's a bug here.

Comment: My mean's if it's right, 13/5, show what? It's an unuseful and untrusted number that is shown me! Am I right?

Comment: 13/5 shows you've more than fulfilled that half of the criteria. The other more difficult to describe bit is your problem.

Comment: You can make use of [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240349/230506) to find out how to check your progress towards the badge

Answer (score 35):

No bug here.

The [Curious badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4127/curious) has two criteria to be awarded:

1. Ask a good question on 5 separate days
2. Maintain a positive question record

You did fulfil the first, on 13 days, and that is what you see, but failed the second. It's even clearly stated in the profile when clicking the "Curious" badge in there:

> [image]

[This other answer by Robert](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/263352/152859) covers the whole aspect of why you failed that second criteria and how to fix it.

Comment: I misunderstand positive question record. I have these questions that I didn't get negative score and it keep positives: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31267833/return-views-by-partialview-method)-(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30978962/how-make-custom-helper-for-ajax-actionlink)-(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26602044/asp-mvc-loose-list-values-of-view-model-on-submit)-(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26646249/order-a-list-by-a-property-namestring-value)-(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30681656/change-mouse-cursor-position-to-focused-control).Not enough to get badge?

Comment: I agree it's quite confusing and not simple to grasp, but there is formula as explained in the other answer and in the links it contains. Based on the formula, you have more questions that got deleted, only a mod can actually find them all.

Comment: @SiamakFerdos You currently have 7 negatively scored questions, 3 closed questions, and 9 deleted questions. `(31 - 7 - 3 - 9) / 31 = 0.39` - You need to have a score of 0.5 to get the badge.

Comment: Robert's answer links to yet another "this answer". In there I found some details about the actual calculation (like the "13" in the sample here), which includes deleted (which seem to count for 3 ...), closed, etc (to be subtracted from upvoted questions). And then the OPer of a deleted question cannot see deleted questions anymore after a while either. So that makes it impossible to actually "verify" your own score (the "13" part), and also how many more "good questions" will be needed. Is there any meta.SE question you're aware of to suggest clarifying (visualizing) all this somehow?

Comment: @Pierre I'm afraid there isn't, I did search for such post before posting my own answer.

Comment: Merci (oeps: thank you) for the (extremely fast) confirmation (I did some similar searches). So would you agree that it may be an interesting feature request "I" should post (which is what I'm considering)?

Comment: @Pierre sure, go ahead, just try to be as clear and focused on the actual request as possible. Good luck! :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard : Done ...

Comment: Cheers @Pierre and thanks for the quick response! :)

Comment: Probably this has to be stated in some very clear way in the same pop-up where we see "Curious 13/5". It is indeed very misleading to see that you've completed the criteria (which is only 5 judging from the UI), but still not awarded.

Comment: @Ollie Letting you know that another editor rolled your edit back, because "fulfil" [is the correct British spelling](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/fulfil).

Comment: @SonictheMaskedWerehog ohh.  Thank you for notifying me.

Comment: We should have a progress bar then on our question experience. Like how many more question upvotes do I need to get this badge?

Comment: @EvanCarroll it's not just upvotes, it's about overall questions status: closed. deleted, etc.

Answer (score 16):

You have some negatively scored deleted questions. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26479693/set-c-sharp-value-in-razor-after-html-element-in-mvc-net) for instance and probably others. You've also [one that you haven't deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953714/whats-default-datatype-of-jquerys-ajax-and-get-methods).

You could try improving them and then undeleting them to see whether you can rescue them. Alternatively you're just going to have to ask more good questions to balance out the deleted bad ones. See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/256477/188189) for more details on the calculation.

Comment: How did you find them?? Some secret diamond on SO? Anyway only questions have effect on that specific bug, so if only one OP position is rather good. :)

Comment: [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26650503/not-able-to-make-a-html-visible-in-jquery/26650661) is answer, not a question. [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26690704/common-jquery-scripts-for-a-website/26690805) is deleted and shouldn't calculate and the third yes you're right...

Comment: @ShadowWizard [Way Back Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20141102055703/http://stackoverflow.com/users/4164585/siamak-ferdos)

Comment: lol, genius! Never thought profile pages are also archived