# Why didn't my latest (well-received) question go towards my "Curious" badge?

Tags: support, badges

I've posted my fifth well-received question:

[image: question list]

However, I still seem to be stuck on *4 out of 5* for the *Curious* badge:

[image: Badge progress indicator]

Any idea what I've done wrong?

This question is different from [a similar question on the 'Curious' badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263351/why-i-havent-i-received-the-curious-badge), because that question pertains to having more than five well-received questions and still not getting the badge. In my case, I seem to have five well-received questions but Stack Overflow is telling me I only have four out of five.

Comment: I'm not sure it is.  I've edited the question to explain why.

Comment: @gnat The "positive question record" isn't the issue here (wasn't even mentioned in the question). I think it's a matter of the appropriate script not having run yet, but can't find any info on the scheduling of said script. (Also, lebelinoz: the criteria is not "ask five well-received questions" but "ask a well-received question on five separate days". You seem to have done this, too, unless there are deleted questions you asked on certain days which will negate those days.)

Comment: at the time of this comment one of those questions were posted 3 hours ago. possibly the 5th day hasn't been registered

Comment: Thanks, that must be it.  I always suspected some stack exchange badges are distributed on some kind of daily schedule.

Comment: Looks like a caching issue. You have the badge now.