# Ongoing problems with "ask a well-received question" counter

Tags: support, badges

I have asked 9 well-received questions over 8 days, yet my count is still 6/30 on the *Inquisitive* badge:

[image]

I've had this problem before:  [Why didn't my latest (well-received) question go towards my "Curious" badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/294845/why-didnt-my-latest-well-received-question-go-towards-my-curious-badge)

The answer, it turns out, was some kind of caching issue.  Is that still the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicate, on hold, closed posts are not consider in the curious and inquisitive badge counts.

I can see only 6 positive posts up to Yesterday. Today's positive post is not yet added in the count.

In [your Stack Overflow questions tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4187933/lebelinoz?tab=questions&sort=activity), I can see 6 positive posts only

[image: Positive posts]

Comment: Ah, I can't see that "Duplicate not count" flag.  I understand now.  I'll just wait for the "Today" post to come through.

Comment: @lebelinoz it's clear in the original announcement that closed questions are not counted, and duplicate *is* closed.