# Why is the 'question record' not shown in the profile?

Tags: feature-request, questions, badge-progress

There are multiple users out there who don't understand why they haven't been awarded with the "curious" Badge.

[Like this user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263351/why-i-havent-i-received-the-curious-badge) who had to recieve an explaination of how the index is calculated.

However, what I don't understand is why the index is not calculated by the system and available for the users without the need to be calculated by hand.

It would be much easier and more transparent for the users to know where they stand. There are so many situations in which you can't tell for certain  what your current question record index is and seeing a direct impact would make people a lot more careful to ask badly formatted questions (question ban) or work for a better record in order to earn the curious badge.
I think you should have an index of how well you're doing at any time.
Same goes for answers and comments.