# Badge: socratic 103/100

Tags: support, badges, asking-days-badges

On the [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tour) site, I've asked enough well-received questions (103/100) to get the [Socratic badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for/67399#67399), but I haven't gotten it.

Why?

Comment: Maybe not an exact dupe, but you can [use my snippet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/324961/323179) to calculate how far away you are from a positive question record.

Comment: Did the system recommend you as the next badge to earn (i.e., you didn't change it from its default or "recommended" selection)? If so, you may consider supporting [this feature request of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357447/dont-recommend-the-asking-days-badge-series-in-the-user-profile-if-user-doesnt) that asks that the system not automatically select asking days badges as recommended badges unless you have a positive question record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add on to the other answer- In order to earn the Socratic badge, you need to have not only asked well-received questions on 100 separate days, but also have maintained a "positive question record." You've done the first part, but you probably haven't done the second.

> A positive question record means you don't have many closed, downvoted, or deleted questions, overall. The formula is:
>
> (total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)/total questions ≥ 0.5
>
> Remember that a question that has been downvoted and closed and deleted count three times in this calculation.
>  <sub>([Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290545/how-is-a-positive-question-record-calculated))</sub>

So you could use the formula and find the values by going to your 'questions' page and counting the number of closed, deleted, or negative questions you have.

(It would probably be nice if the badge-progress-tracker factored that in when it told you how many more questions you had to ask, but that could be even more confusing. See: [Give users a way to see their "Positive Question Record" score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234963/give-users-a-way-to-see-their-positive-question-record-score))

Answer (score 4):

> [image]

According to badge description you need [positive question record](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/290546/339911) as well.